# O que é "One Level of indentation"?

Tags: terminologia

Estava esses dias atrás assistindo a essa [vídeo aula no Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/simple-rules-for-simpler-code/episodes/3), onde há uma explicação que ensina a evitar o acumulo de muito código em um método, separando em vários métodos com responsabilidades específicas e reduzindo assim o tamanho da indentação - pelo menos foi o que entendi, me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

Percebi também que existe o mesmo "ensinamento" [nesse link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cellfish/2009/08/16/object-calisthenics-rule-1-use-one-level-of-indentation-per-method/), que me parece ser o blog da Microsoft.

O que é curioso é que, nessas vídeos aulas do Laracast, geralmente os assuntos tratados são do framework em PHP chamado Laravel. Não sei se é só uma coincidência, mas eu vi que o link acima é da Microsoft, e o criador do Laravel, o Taylor Otwell, disse numa vídeo-aula que, antes de programar em PHP, programava em ASP - que é da Microsoft.

Pode parecer irrelevante essa última colocação, mas ela é importante para minha dúvida:
Esse é um padrão específico ao desenvolvimento do ASP (ou qualquer outra coisa da Microsoft, como C# e etc), ou realmente esse "One Level of Indentation" é uma padrão de projeto ou um padrão de codificação?

**Nota**: Não conheço muito sobre as "coisas" da Microsoft, então perdoem-me se falei alguma bobagem.

Comment: object calisthenics, cai na categoria boas práticas ou se prefrerir recomendações [aqui](https://github.com/object-calisthenics/phpcs-calisthenics-rules) tem algumas outras, isso serve para qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Grande @rray. Preciosas informações :D

Comment: Podia ter isso em português, hein :D

Comment: Repositories e Service Layers ajudam nisso. Ao invés do Controller ter contato direto com o Model, esses repositórios e camadas de serviços fazem todo o trabalho. O que ajuda em pouco código no Controller, na Identação e evita acumulo de códigos repetidos.

Comment: @rray depois da sua referência, pude "aprender" a como a pesquisar sobre o assunto. Acho que vale a pena ver isso aqui [Object Calisthenics - Português](http://rogerio.me/object-calisthenics/)

Comment: É uma "boa prática", ou seja, algo que se você seguir só por seguir, vai te ferrar.

Comment: Para a prática ser boa tem que ter prática. Tem gente que sai usando os padrões de projeto e "boas práticas" só porque acha bonitinho, sem entender o sentido :D

Comment: Não sei se as tags microsoft e laravel se encaixam nessa pergunta ...

Comment: Como perdi o *timing* da pergunta não vou responder, mas esta é uma dessas regras esdrúxulas que alguém inventa e um monte de bobo segue. Não há vantagem algum em forçar isto. Se algo deve ter apenas um nível de *indent* deve ser porque faz sentido ali e não porque uma regra tola manda. Assim como é ruim juntar várias responsabilidades em um único método, separar responsabilidades que estão intimamente relacionadas também pode ser ruim. Complicação sem ganho.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eles estão se referindo a indentação do código. Para manter a legibilidade do código eles estão defendendo que deve ser usado apenas um nível de indentação.

O exemplo a seguir estaria fora desse padrão.

```
public void func1(){
    for( i in list){//Primeiro nível de indentação
       if( i.foo == true ){//Segundo nível de identação
         //faça coisas
       }
    }
}
```

Para corrigi-lo você deve eliminar o segundo nível de indentação transportando ele para dentro de uma função.

```
public void func1(){
    for( i in list){//Primeiro nível de indentação
       facaCoisaComI(i);
    }
}

public void facaCoisaComObjeto(Objeto i){
   if( i.foo == true ){
         //faça coisas
   }
}
```

Esse padrão não específico de nenhuma tecnologia ou linguagem. É uma boa prática para melhorar a legibilidade do seu código.

Answer (score 8):

Esse tipo de recomendação independe de linguagem. Não se prenda muito a definições de padrão de projeto ou codificação, ou se algo vem da Microsoft ou do PHP.

Tente separar o conceito da implementação em si. Você pode muito bem aplicar esse conceito em COBOL também, qual o problema?

Procure analisar o que as linguagens tem em comum. É a [orientação a objetos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos)? Então muito provavelmente você consegue aplicar os [princípios de SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Seguir tudo que dizem que é boa prática também não é uma boa ideia. *Singleton* já foi considerado uma boa ideia, mas no contexto atual é considerado um [*Anti-Pattern*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipadr%C3%B5es_de_projeto_de_software).

Resumindo, procure interpretar as ideias e seja crítico, entenda o por que dizem que tal coisa é boa e se faz sentido no contexto que você está aplicando.

Comment: Bons pontos, bem feita. Minha própria COBOL terá so um nível de recuo, mas que a ajuda para a compreensão poderia facilmente estar sob por ter um multi-screen "case statement" . Ele não está a seguir as palavras que recebe a boa prática, mas compreender a intenção, e não apenas a letra da lei.

Answer (score 5):

Isso é independente da linguagem ou ambiente. É apenas sugestão de boa prática na escrita de códigos. E para não achar que apenas falo por falar, eu programava em ASP (clássico), antes de entrar no PHP, por volta de 1999. A recomendação de níveis de identação é também questão de escolha pessoal. Não há nenhuma regra ou mesmo um padrão amplamente aceito que diga que deve ser assim com apenas um nível. Aliás, particularmente discordo de ter apenas um nível pois imagine a situação como no exemplo postado pelo Vinicius Zaramella,

```
for( i in list){//Primeiro nível de indentação
   if( i.foo == true ){//Segundo nível de identação
     //imagine que aqui precise fazer apenas 1 ou 2 linhas de código
     //particularmente acho desnecessário ter o trabalho de criar um novo método para algo tão pequeno.
   }
}
```

Independente disso, sempre evite muitos níveis de identação, como

```
if () {
    if () {
        if () {
            if () {
                if () {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui temos 4 níveis. Se é aceitável ou não, isso dependerá do contexto, do real motivo em usar dessa forma. Contudo, se conseguir reduzir é sempre melhor.

Quando perceber que está criando condicionais dentro de condicionais, pare um pouco e reflita sobre a lógica. Pois quando chega nesse "espagueti de condicionais", pode ter algo errado ou algo que pode ser melhor escrito.